# Add http request id in all wildfly server logs

Tags: java, log4j, wildfly, slf4j

In my application runtime, I have HTTP requestid.

So I want all my logs to be prefixed with this parameter automatically, without explicit sending of this parameter with:

```
log.error("{} My message", requestId);
```

Our application is running under wildfly 8.2 and uses slf4j facade for logging.

I have following questions:

1. How should I configure my wildfly logging subsystem to write requestId parameter to all application logs automatically?
2. Is it possible at all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this ID stored (header, URL parameter, etc.)?  Is this a JAX-RS application or servlets?

Comment: Yes, this parameter goes from header and is stored in specific InvocationData object that is accessible with JNDI at any point of code on server. Application has both JAX-RS and Servlet parts.

Comment: You'd probably have to intercept the request before the logged message and add an MDC entry. Then adjust the formatter pattern to print the MDC value.

Comment: Thanks, James, I'll think about it